# ErrorException in .php -- Response is returning blank

Tags: php, angularjs, json, laravel-5

I'm working in an app that has its frontend on angularjs and uses laravel 5 as backend. Im trying to upload files, but in the console, the response is a blank space.

This is my controller in angular that handle the files

```
    vm.makeFile = function(newFile){
        vm.shipmentObject.files=[];
        vm.newDateFile= new Date();
        vm.newDateFile = $filter('date')(vm.newDateFile, "yyyy-MM-dd h:mm:ss");
        vm.shipmentObject.files.push({
            "id":23,
            "shipment_id":43,
            "user_id":20,
            "date":vm.newDateFile,
            "file": "vm.shipmentObject.file",
            "fileName":"aguacate",
            "fileType":"jpg",
            "status":"I"
        });

        ShipmentResource.insertFile({files:vm.shipmentObject.files}).success(function(response){
            console.log(response);
            console.log("FILE INSERTED CORRECTLY");
        });

            console.log(vm.shipmentObject.files);
    };
```

And this is my controller in laravel that handles the files

```
 public function makeFile(Request $request)
    {
        if(isset($request->files) && is_array($request->files)){
            $fileArray=[];
            foreach($request->files as $key=>$fileEntity){
                $file= new File();
                $file->file=$fileEntity['file'];
                $file->shipment_id=$fileEntity['shipment_id'];
                $file->user_id=$fileEntity['user_id'];
                $file->date=date('Y,m,d,G,i,s');
                $file->fileName=$fileEntity['fileName'];
                $file->fileType=$fileEntity['fileType'];
                $file->status=$fileEntity['status'];
                $file->save();

                array_push($fileArray, $file);
            }

        }
  return response()->json();
    }
```

In that way, the console logs are printing in the browser this:

[image]

A BLANK RESPONSE,
At the end of the laravel controller if i change this

> return response()->json()

for this

> return response()->json($fileArray)

The response is a 500 error

> ErrorException in ShipmentController.php line 132: Undefined variable:
>   fileArray in ShipmentController.php line 132 at
>   HandleExceptions->handleError('8', 'Undefined variable: fileArray',
>   'C:\xampp\htdocs\zignyWS\app\Http\Controllers\ShipmentController.php',
>   '132', array('request' => object(Request))) in ShipmentController.php
>   line 132

the line 132 is this one -> return response()->json($fileArray)

I dont know where the problem is, it may be because of the way that are sending the request? 
[image]

I think the problem its in the backend side...

I'm stuck in this, after that I need to display the file in the app if its a pdf and add validations only to upload xls,pdf and doc files., but please help me with this blank response issue first

---

## Update

> The success method is deprecated. I'd recommend changing it to then(). – [Mike Feltman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2528234/mike-feltman)

Its changed now. It looks like this

```
    ShipmentResource.insertFile({files:vm.shipmentObject.fil‌​es}) 
      .then(function(response){
        console.log(response);
        console.log("FILE INSERTED CORRECTLY");
        console.log(response);
        console.log(vm.shipmentObject.files); 
    }, function(err){ 
        console.log(err);
    });
    vm.shipmentObject.newFile="";
    console.log(vm.shipmentObject.files);
};
```

Comment: The success method is deprecated. I'd recommend changing it to then().

Comment: Its changed now. It looks like this 
    ShipmentResource.insertFile({files:vm.shipmentObject.files})
    .then(function(response){
     console.log(response);
     console.log("FILE INSERTED CORRECTLY");
     console.log(response);
     console.log(vm.shipmentObject.files);
    }, function(err){
     console.log(err);
    });
    vm.shipmentObject.newFile="";

     console.log(vm.shipmentObject.files);
   };

Comment: but it keeps returning this error ErrorException in ShipmentController.php line 132:
Undefined variable: fileArray @MikeFeltman

Comment: Yeah, that was just an aside. The error is definitely on the server side.

Comment: JPG files are a binary format. If you use content type `application/json`, binary files will stringify as empty.

Comment: Please show the code for the `ShipmentResource.insertFile` method. We need to see how the binary file part of the object is processed.

Comment: ShipmentResource.insertFile = function(file){
  return $http.post(WS.BaseURL + '/shipment/file/', file);
 };   its like this @georgeawg

Comment: Right now the `file` property of each object is a string. If you replace that string with an actual file from a [FileList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList), that code will fail to upload the file data. I look forward to your next Stackoverflow question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the array declaration on the server side is incorrect. I think it should be `$fileArray=array();`

Comment: I make that change and the error its the same. in the line 132 return response()->json($fileArray); Undefined variable: fileArray @MikeFeltman

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake. It was in the server side as i was thinking.
The declaration of the fileArray was missplaced, the right place to put it, was before the first IF. Like this

```
public function makeFile(Request $request)
    {
        $fileArray = [];
    if (isset($request->files) && is_array($request->files)) {
        foreach ($request->files as $key => $fileEntity) {
            $file= new File();
            $file->file=$fileEntity['file'];
            $file->shipment_id=$fileEntity['shipment_id'];
            $file->user_id=$fileEntity['user_id'];
            $file->date=date('Y,m,d,G,i,s');
            $file->fileName=$fileEntity['fileName'];
            $file->fileType=$fileEntity['fileType'];
            $file->status=$fileEntity['status'];
            $file->save();

            $fileArray[] = $file;
        }
    }
    return response()->json($fileArray);
    }
```